# Can I push other branch to remote as current?

Tags: git

I've prematurely deleted remote branch, before merging to all productive branches.

I've got the branch locally, but I couldn't find out, how to push it WITHOUT checkouting it.

I know I can `git push <remote> <branch`> to push current branch under another remote name.

But how to push branch other than current to the remote?

Comment: I believe you just need a colon: `git push $remote $local_branch:$remote_branch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name the local branch by separating it from the remote name with a `:`.  eg:

```
git push $remote $local_branch:$remote_branch
```

Answer (score -1):

To push a specific branch, run `git push <remote> <branch>`.